# Insert node not values in end of linked lists

Tags: c, arrays, linked-list

Lets say I have some linked lists already available and I want to store first node of each individual list into another list so that I can recall this list to display the original lists. I think we have to use two different structures. I am already successful in retaining original lists and displaying them using Array of first nodes of individual lists but I want to create a linked list of individual list to implement same. It has the expected output but as I said I want to use linked list instead of array of nodes.

Now this is how I am trying to solve the problem to replace the array of linked lists to linked list of first nodes, I am getting crashes whenever I try to debug code. Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node{
    int number;
    struct node*next;
};

typedef struct node Node;
Node* insertValue(Node * list, int value);
void display(Node*);

struct list_of_nodes {
    Node *list;
    struct list_of_nodes *next;
};

 typedef struct list_of_nodes ListNode;

 ListNode* insertNode(ListNode* head,Node* node);

int main()
{
ListNode *head=NULL;
Node *globalList = NULL, *lists[100];
int nbrOfLists, listNo, nbrOfVal, valNo, val,i=0,k;

CHECKER:
printf("\n\n Enter the number of lists (1 to 100):");
scanf("%d", &nbrOfLists);

if(nbrOfLists <= 0 || nbrOfLists > 100) //handling exceptional cases
    {
        printf("\n \n Number of Lists should be between 1 to 100");  // since array of node pointers contains 100 elements
        goto CHECKER;
    }


for(listNo = 0; listNo < nbrOfLists; listNo++)
{
    printf("\n\n Enter the number of inputs to the list %d: \n ",listNo+1);
    scanf("%d", &nbrOfVal);
    lists[listNo] = NULL;

    for(valNo = 0; valNo < nbrOfVal; valNo++)   // to enter values in each individual list
    {
        printf("Enter node value %d:", valNo+1);
        scanf("%d", &val);

        // Here we insert the value in both lists
        lists[listNo]= insertValue(lists[listNo], val);  // original list has to be retained so storing in array lists
        globalList = insertValue(globalList, val);   // inserting node in combined list. This prevents an extra loop and merges the list elements into one.
    }

    head=insertNode(head,lists[listNo]); // CRASHING HERE 

    printf("\n  The list %d is: ",listNo+1);
    display(lists[listNo]);  // display each list after input
}

printf("\n\n\n THE FINAL LIST IS: ");
display(globalList);  //display combined list

printf("\n\n THE LISTS WERE: ");

while(i<nbrOfLists){   //original lists displayed
    k=i+1;
    printf("\n\n The list %d is: ",k);
    display(lists[i]);
    i++;
}

printf("\n\n");
return 0;
}

ListNode* insertNode(ListNode* head, Node* node){
ListNode *newNode, *m;
newNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
newNode->list=node;

if(newNode == NULL)
{
   newNode->next=NULL;  // inserting first node
   return newNode;
}

m = head;
while(m->next)  // checking for right position in ordered list for new node
{
  m = m->next;
}
newNode->next = m->next;  // inserting new node
m->next = newNode;
return head;

}
Node* insertValue(Node * list, int value)   // function to insert node in ordered manner into list
{
Node *newNode, *m;
newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
newNode->number=value;

if(list == NULL)
{
   newNode->next=NULL;  // inserting first node
   return newNode;
}

if(value < list->number)
{
   newNode->next = list;  // inserting in end
   return newNode;
}

m = list;
while(m->next)  // checking for right position in ordered list for new node
{
   if(value < m->next->number)
       break;
   m = m->next;
}
newNode->next = m->next;  // inserting new node
m->next = newNode;
return list;
}

void display(Node*nodex){ // display node values in list

printf("%d ->",nodex->number);
nodex=nodex->next;

   if(nodex)
        return display(nodex);
   else
        return 0;
  }
```

Here is the code which shows expected results but with Array of nodes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>

struct node{
    int number;
    struct node*next;
};

typedef struct node Node;
Node* insertValue(Node *list, int value);
void display(Node*);

int main()
{

    Node *globalList = NULL, *lists[100];
    int nbrOfLists, listNo, nbrOfVal, valNo, val, i = 0, k;

CHECKER:
    printf("\n\n Enter the number of lists (1 to 100):");
    scanf("%d", &nbrOfLists);

    if(nbrOfLists <= 0 || nbrOfLists > 100) //handling exceptional cases
    {
        printf("\n \n Number of Lists should be between 1 to 100");  // since array of node pointers contains 100 elements
        goto CHECKER;
    }

    for(listNo = 0; listNo < nbrOfLists; listNo++)
    {
        printf("\n\n Enter the number of inputs to the list %d: \n ", listNo + 1);
        scanf("%d", &nbrOfVal);
        lists[listNo] = NULL;

        for(valNo = 0; valNo < nbrOfVal; valNo++)   // to enter values in each individual list
        {
            printf("Enter node value %d:", valNo + 1);
            scanf("%d", &val);

            // Here we insert the value in both lists
            lists[listNo] = insertValue(lists[listNo], val);  // original list has to be retained so storing in array lists
            globalList = insertValue(globalList, val);   // inserting node in combined list. This prevents an extra loop and merges the list elements into one.
        }

        printf("\n  The list %d is: ", listNo + 1);
        display(lists[listNo]);  // display each list after input
    }

    printf("\n\n\n THE FINAL LIST IS: ");
    display(globalList);  //display combined list

    printf("\n\n THE LISTS WERE: ");

    while(i < nbrOfLists){   //original lists displayed
        k = i + 1;
        printf("\n\n The list %d is: ", k);
        display(lists[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}

Node* insertValue(Node *list, int value)   // function to insert node in    ordered manner into list
{
    Node *newNode, *m;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->number = value;

    if(list == NULL)
    {
        newNode->next = NULL;  // inserting first node
        return newNode;
    }

    if(value < list->number)
    {
        newNode->next = list;  // inserting in end
        return newNode;
    }

    m = list;
    while(m->next)  // checking for right position in ordered list for new node
    {
        if(value < m->next->number)
            break;
        m = m->next;
    }

    newNode->next = m->next;  // inserting new node
    m->next = newNode;
    return list;
}

void display(Node *nodex){ // display node values in list

    printf("%d ->", nodex->number);
    nodex = nodex->next;

    if(nodex)
        return display(nodex);
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Please let me know if you do not understood the problem.

Comment: You will need a second list node type, `struct list_of_nodes { Node *list; struct list_of_nodes *next; };` and you'll need your second set of list management functions to handle that.  Or you have to play some fancy tricks, such as changing `struct node` so that it holds a `void *data;` instead of `int number;`, and then arrange for the 'list of ints' code to work with this, and add the 'list of nodes' code too.  Or migrate to C++ and use a templated list type specialized to the different types.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I have the same idea but can you apply the same in the above code and show me. I have tried that myself, but didn't quiet work for me. Also inserting node function is available. Please try and let me know. I will also be trying from my end. I can't use C++ sorry.

Comment: Show us what you tried that didn't work, and we can help you fix it.  You've got a list mechanism that you say works (I've not tested it, so I reserve judgement on that).  If you're happy with it, you should be able to clone it with edits such that it deals with the currently hypothetical `struct list_of_nodes` type, and instead of taking an `int value`, it takes a `Node *value`.  It should just be a systematic edit.  Of course, you already have working code to print lists, so your 'list_of_nodes' code will swiftly have working code that prints lists of lists.  I understand "cannot use C++".

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Please debug the code, just copy and paste it into Dev C or codeblocks. You will understand how it works. Next, I cannot use C++ because I need this program for my assignment in C programming. I am trying from my end. You can easily try out, I will rate you up as well. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I understand how the code you've shown works (or is supposed to work), yes.  I don't understand how the code you've not shown doesn't work — primarily because you've not shown it.  It seems sufficiently straight-forward that I'm not sure why you're having problems, but that's often the case.  Once you show the erroneous code, the problems can be diagnosed efficiently.  Until then, I'm not going to write your code for you — I disagree with enough of the structure of what I see that I'd want to rewrite it all, and then it wouldn't be your code after all. _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  For instance, you don't check that the input operations succeed.  If the user types 'a' instead of 1, everything else is going to be working with indeterminate inputs.  You repeatedly prompt for a number, and then scan for it.  You should have a function that does that; it can handle EOF and data format errors too.  And you can use it in a `while` loop instead of needing the `CHECKER:` lable.

Comment: Ok I used your structure definition. I am having an error.

Comment: if(val==0) 
head->list=lists[listNo]; head=head->next;

Error: invalid argument '->'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75599/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-abhishek-singh).

Comment: If I use Nodex *head, then I see output crashing after first input i.e. at val==0.

What is Nodex? typedef struct list_of_nodes Nodex;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After considerable discussion in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75599/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-abhishek-singh), I ended up using this code which is closely related to the last version in the question:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node
{
    int number;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node Node;
Node *insertValue(Node *list, int value);
void display(Node *);

struct list_of_nodes
{
    Node *list;
    struct list_of_nodes *next;
};

typedef struct list_of_nodes ListNode;

ListNode *insertNode(ListNode *head, Node *node);

int main(void)
{
    ListNode *head = NULL;
    Node *globalList = NULL, *lists[100];
    int nbrOfLists, listNo, nbrOfVal, valNo, val, i = 0, k;

CHECKER:
    printf("\n\n Enter the number of lists (1 to 100):");
    scanf("%d", &nbrOfLists);

    if (nbrOfLists <= 0 || nbrOfLists > 100)
    {
        printf("\n \n Number of Lists should be between 1 to 100");
        goto CHECKER;
    }

    for (listNo = 0; listNo < nbrOfLists; listNo++)
    {
        printf("\n\n Enter the number of inputs to the list %d: \n ", listNo + 1);
        scanf("%d", &nbrOfVal);
        lists[listNo] = NULL;

        for (valNo = 0; valNo < nbrOfVal; valNo++)
        {
            printf("Enter node value %d:", valNo + 1);
            scanf("%d", &val);

            lists[listNo] = insertValue(lists[listNo], val);
            globalList = insertValue(globalList, val);
        }

        head = insertNode(head, lists[listNo]);

        printf("\n  The list %d is: ", listNo + 1);
        display(lists[listNo]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n THE FINAL LIST IS: ");
    display(globalList);

    printf("\n\n THE LISTS WERE: ");

    while (i < nbrOfLists)
    {
        k = i + 1;
        printf("\n\n The list %d is: ", k);
        display(lists[i]);
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}

ListNode *insertNode(ListNode *head, Node *node)
{
    ListNode *newNode, *m;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    newNode->list = node;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory in %s\n", __func__);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (head == NULL)
        return newNode;

    m = head;
    while (m->next)
    {
        m = m->next;
    }
    newNode->next = m->next;
    m->next = newNode;
    return head;
}

Node *insertValue(Node *list, int value)
{
    Node *newNode, *m;
    newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newNode->number = value;
    newNode->next = NULL;

    if (list == NULL)
        return newNode;

    if (value < list->number)
    {
        newNode->next = list;
        return newNode;
    }

    m = list;
    while (m->next)
    {
        if (value < m->next->number)
            break;
        m = m->next;
    }
    newNode->next = m->next;
    m->next = newNode;
    return list;
}

void display(Node *nodex)
{
    printf("%d ->", nodex->number);
    nodex = nodex->next;
    if (nodex)
        display(nodex);
}
```

With a sample data file (`ll7.data`):

```
3
6 26 22 83 96 89 69
10 87 33 5 36 85 34 0 25 57 99
5 49 44 27 75 82
```

I compiled `ll7.c` above using:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror ll7.c -o ll7
$
```

And ran it under [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) which noted that the code leaks like a sieve (because there isn't a free in sight), but otherwise gave it a clean bill of health.

```
$ valgrind --suppressions=suppressions ./ll7 < ll7.data
==7696== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7696== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7696== Using Valgrind-3.11.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7696== Command: ./ll7
==7696== 
--7696-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option
--7696-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 2 times)
--7696-- UNKNOWN mach_msg unhandled MACH_SEND_TRAILER option (repeated 4 times)


 Enter the number of lists (1 to 100):

 Enter the number of inputs to the list 1: 
 Enter node value 1:Enter node value 2:Enter node value 3:Enter node value 4:Enter node value 5:Enter node value 6:
  The list 1 is: 22 ->26 ->69 ->83 ->89 ->96 ->

 Enter the number of inputs to the list 2: 
 Enter node value 1:Enter node value 2:Enter node value 3:Enter node value 4:Enter node value 5:Enter node value 6:Enter node value 7:Enter node value 8:Enter node value 9:Enter node value 10:
  The list 2 is: 0 ->5 ->25 ->33 ->34 ->36 ->57 ->85 ->87 ->99 ->

 Enter the number of inputs to the list 3: 
 Enter node value 1:Enter node value 2:Enter node value 3:Enter node value 4:Enter node value 5:
  The list 3 is: 27 ->44 ->49 ->75 ->82 ->


 THE FINAL LIST IS: 0 ->5 ->22 ->25 ->26 ->27 ->33 ->34 ->36 ->44 ->49 ->57 ->69 ->75 ->82 ->83 ->85 ->87 ->89 ->96 ->99 ->

 THE LISTS WERE: 

 The list 1 is: 22 ->26 ->69 ->83 ->89 ->96 ->

 The list 2 is: 0 ->5 ->25 ->33 ->34 ->36 ->57 ->85 ->87 ->99 ->

 The list 3 is: 27 ->44 ->49 ->75 ->82 ->

==7696== 
==7696== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7696==     in use at exit: 43,752 bytes in 471 blocks
==7696==   total heap usage: 551 allocs, 80 frees, 49,880 bytes allocated
==7696== 
==7696== LEAK SUMMARY:
==7696==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==7696==    indirectly lost: 688 bytes in 43 blocks
==7696==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7696==    still reachable: 29,998 bytes in 310 blocks
==7696==         suppressed: 13,034 bytes in 116 blocks
==7696== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==7696== 
==7696== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7696== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
$
```

The prompting output isn't really wanted when the input comes from a file, and that's why the numbers aren't seen, too.  When you type at the terminal, the terminal driver echoes what you type to the screen.  When the data comes from a file, you don't see the characters as they're read.

The suppressions file lists and suppresses a variety of leaks from the Mac OS X 10.10.3 Yosemite runtime system.  That's why there's so much memory in use, too; the runtime system uses a lot of memory.

Were it all my code, there'd be a lot that would be done differently.  There is a lot of error checking that should be added and refactorization (especially 'extract function') that could/should be done, but those changes were not made to preserve some semblance to the code posted in the question.

Comment: Is there a way to improve the efficiency of the above code. I mean like using something else instead of nested for loops.

Comment: It depends on what you're after.  If the global list is what you need, then you don't need the nested loops.  But if you're interested in the individual lists, then nested loops are pretty much sine qua non, and efficiency is a red-herring (the code is dominated by I/O, especially the write I/O for prompts, etc, so speeding up is best done by eliminating the superfluous I/O.  Until you have measured where the code spends its time, you won't know how to speed it up.

Comment: For example, if you define that each list of numbers must be on a single line, you could forego the clumsy counts of the number of lines and the number of entries in each list and simply have the numbers entered.  The code could then read whole lines, parse the line into separate numbers.

Comment: You could also read the numbers into an array, sort the array, and then arrange to use a function to convert the array into a list without having to sort the data each time.  The existing code is great if the lists are presented in reverse order (highest first) — the insertion time is linear — but horrid if the data is already sorted — giving quadratic performance.  It all depends on what you're trying to do, and what the real data looks like.

Comment: I would strongly recommend concentrating on issues like freeing the lists cleanly and improving the printing (so there isn't a stray `->` at the end of a list, for example) over worrying about 'performance'.

Comment: Yes one for loop can be avoided by parsing the line to numbers. How about goto statement?

Comment: The `goto` wouldn't be there at all in my code. I'd have an explicit `while` loop, if I bothered to let them have another go after making a mistake. It depends on whether you think people are going to be typing at your program very often.  I object to counting for computers; they're quicker at it than I am.  So 'how many lists' and 'how many numbers in this list' are annoying.  And I'd feed the data from a file — witness the tests I described in the answer and in the chat commentary. So, I would accept a valid number and stop processing with an error message on an error. But YMMV, as they say.

Comment: I looked at the posted code (how come the edits are in answers rather than edit of the posted code?)  1) always check (!= NULL) the returned value from malloc (and family) to assure the operation was successful,  2) always check the returned value from scanf (and family) to assure the input/conversion operation was successful.  3) Your problem statement says your adding a new list of pointers to a series of linked lists.  The posted code put every linked list  entry in the new list of pointers to linked lists   4) there is no clear definition of the 'head' pointers for the new linked list.

Comment: strongly suggest breaking the code into small/simple/well defined functions.  Then debug each of the sub functions individually.  Then debug them together.   While at the process of breaking the code into simple functions, be sure to incorporate the many suggested fixes.  Both for the project functionality and to eliminate the many poor coding practices, like that GOTO and failing to check the returned value from malloc and scanf

Comment: @user3629249: All those points are mentioned in the chat, I believe.  I did enough to get it to work when the wind was fair; it is not bomb-proof code.  There are enough other changes that I'd want to make in something more nearly bomb-proof that the result would not be recognizably related to the OPs code.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Just about 5 minutes before I finished this, 
a new version of the code was posted
that seems to do what I recommended, but the new function was not quite right.

Here is one problem:

```
ListNode* insertNode(ListNode* head, Node* node){
  // ... other code here ...
  m = head;
  while(m->next)
```

The first time `insertNode` is called, `head` is a null pointer
(which it *should* be, because the list of lists is still empty at that time).
So this sets `m` to a null pointer, and then attempts to access `m->next` ... oops!

I see this comment:

```
// checking for right position in ordered list for new node
```

Why? What is the "right position"? It appears that the "right position" is
the end of the list of lists; but what is wrong with the beginning?

If you absolutely must have the list of lists come out in the same order in
which the lists were input, then a simpler and more efficient design is to
insert each new list at the start of the list of lists, and when you are
all done, reverse the list of lists.

But you could also just adapt the code from `insertValue` a little more
carefully. Compare this code of `insertValue`:

```
newNode = malloc(sizeof(Node));
newNode->number=value;
if(list == NULL)
```

to this code of `insertNode`:

```
newNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
newNode->list=node;
if(newNode == NULL)
```

Do you see the difference? In `insertValue` the `if` tests the pointer that was passed into the function; in `insertNode` the `if` tests the pointer that you have just assigned by `newNode = malloc(sizeof(ListNode))`. 
Of course `if(newNode == NULL)` will never execute the body of the `if`
(unless something has already gone badly wrong).
What you *need* is to test `if(head == NULL)` so that you can handle
that case correctly.

---

The rest of this refers to the older version of the question.

Among other things that probably aren't doing what they're supposed to,
this piece of code has multiple serious flaws:

```
    if(valNo==0){  // FOR EVERY FIRST NODE IN INDIVIDUAL LIST, I AM TRYING TO INSERT IT INTO LIST OF FIRST NODES
      head->list=malloc(sizeof(Nodex));
      head->list=lists[listNo];
      head=head->next;
    }
```

OK, first major flaw, you are trying to add the new list to the list of lists
before the list is complete. Until the list is complete, you don't know
what node will end up at the head of that list. The first node you *insert*
into the list could end up anywhere in the completed list.
That is not what you want to put in your list of lists.
One thing you should change in the code, therefore, is to move those lines
(the ones I copied) out of the inner `for` loop where they are now;
put them after the end of that loop instead
(and of course delete the `if(valNo==0)`; 
these lines should execute unconditionally).

Next thing, you never allocated a `Nodex` for `head` to point to,
so `head->list` will always be an access error.

Next thing, `head->list=lists[listNo]` overwrites the pointer you just
set with `head->list=malloc(sizeof(Nodex))`; the memory you allocated
with `malloc(sizeof(Nodex))` is immediately leaked. (It was allocated using
the size of the wrong type anyway, since `list` was supposed to point to a
`Node` rather than a `Nodex`, although the `Nodex` is probably at least
large enough so you could get away with that mistake.)

Finally: `head=head->next;`??? Since `head` is the only `Nodex*` that you
declared at the start of the `main()` function, if there were ever a
legitimate `Nodex` in your list, after `head=head->next`
there would be nothing pointing to that `Nodex` any more, at least
nothing that you can find in your program. So if you succeeded in putting
anything in the list of lists, that step would essentially throw it away
(it would become a memory leak).

What you probably should do, for your sanity, is write a function
`Nodex* insertList(Nodex* list_list, Node* value_list)`
that inserts the head pointer of a list, `value_list`,
into your list of lists, analogously to the way
`Node* insertValue(Node * list, int value)` inserts a number into a list,
except that you probably don't need to make `insertList` keep its list
"sorted", so `insertList` should be considerably simpler than `insertValue`.
(In fact it will be so simple that you may be tempted to just write
the code of that function inline in your `main` function. I suggest you
resist the temptation; writing the code inline did not work for you on
the first attempt, and making even very simple functions to do well-defined
things is a good practice.)

Comment: Please check the updated question, I am not using that piece of code anymore. I am reading your answer though

Comment: I am not using the above lines of code as I understood the issue raised by you. Please check the updated code where I use a function to insert nodes instead.

Comment: Looks like you got similar advice elsewhere. (I didn't check the chat.) Does the code work now? Or is there still a problem?

Comment: No it crashes. I have mentioned as a comment in code. I am inserting in outer loop instead using function. Something like this:  head=insertNode(head,lists[listNo]);

It crashes right there. Check function definition.