# Segmentation fault when adding node to linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

```
Node *orderedInsert(Node *p, int newval)
/* Allocates a new Node with data value newval
   and inserts into the ordered list with 
   first node pointer p in such a way that the
   data values in the modified list are in 
   ascending order as the list is traversed.
*/
{
   Node* current = NULL;
   Node* prev = NULL;
   Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
   newNode->next = NULL;
   newNode->data = newval;

   if(newNode == NULL)
      printf("Could not allocate memory for new node");

   current = p;   

   if(p == NULL){

      p = newNode;
      newNode->next = NULL;
      newNode->data = newval;
      return  p;
   }
   else if(newval < p->data){
      newNode->next = p;
      p = newNode;
      return p;
   }
   else{ 
      prev = p;
      current = current->next; 



      while(newNode->data > current->data && current != NULL){

         prev = current;
         current = current->next;
      }
      if(prev->next == NULL){//the error is located somewhere here I think
         prev->next = newNode;
         newNode->data = newval;
         newNode->next = NULL;
         return p;   
      }
      else{
         newNode->next = current;
         prev->next = newNode;
         return p;
      }
   }   
}
```

I am only getting an segmentation fault error when adding a node that is larger than any other node (meaning it will be at the end of the list). It will do fine if I input them in the order 4 3 2 1 or 4 2 1 3 but not if I go 1 2.

Comment: This is inadequate: `if(newNode == NULL)
      printf("Could not allocate memory for new node");` — you have to ensure that the function doesn't use `newNode` so it must either return or exit.  Also, errors should be reported on standard error, not standard output.

Comment: `while(newNode->data > current->data && current != NULL){` should be `while( current != NULL && newNode->data > current->data){`

Comment: Please learn how to use the debugger, and/or learn how to put appropriate print statements into the code so that you can find the problem by looking at the program as it executes, and/or learn how to use `assert()` from `<assert.h>`.  In case of emergency (core dumps), check that pointers are not null before using them: `assert(current != NULL);` or equivalent.

Comment: You are awesome man thank you! So in the while loop when it does the greater than comparison with a NULL that will cause a segmentation fault? I thought it only was caused when you try to modify the memory.

Comment: You can't read `current->next` when `current` is null.  And because you have the test for nullness after, not before, you use `current`, you crash.

Comment: Okay so it was the assignment statement and not the comparison. I tried my best to debug with printf() statements but I glossed over the while loop and was stumped. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Note that: `if(p == NULL){
      p = newNode;
      newNode->next = NULL;
      newNode->data = newval;
      return  p;
   }` can be reduced to `if (p == NULL) return newNode;` because the node is set up immediately after the memory allocation (which should be checked).  If it wasn't you, it was someone with a remarkably similar coding style who got help from me on [this material](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29719445/insert-node-not-values-in-end-of-linked-lists) yesterday.  I'm suffering from deja vu, you might say.  Maybe it is one of your classmates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using your example of adding 1 and 2.

First iteration will hit

```
if(p == NULL){
  p = newNode;
  newNode->next = NULL;
  newNode->data = newval;
  return  p;
}
```

And then next pointer is pointed to NULL.

Then when you add 2, you will hit:

```
else{ 
  prev = p;
  current = current->next; 

  while(newNode->data > current->data && current != NULL){
    ...
  }
```

Here `current->next` is NULL. After assigning it to `current`, `current` is NULL.